# Undesired extra space on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, miktex

Hello I am using MikTex in TexStudios and I have this document:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
\usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}            % Colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

%\addtolength{\voffset}{-40pt}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{20pt}

\setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headheight}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headsep}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\textwidth{-2in}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
%\addtolength\textheight{-3in}
\addtolength\textheight{-2in}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}

%%% Custom sectioning}{sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{%                      % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}          % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}       % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\NewPart}[2]{\section*{\uppercase{#1} #2}}



%%% Begin Document
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    {\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}{Bruce Dickinson}}\\
    Address
    \href{mailto:mymail@somewhere.com}{mymail@somewhere.com}\\
    07575349875437
    \end{document}
```

and I don't understand why there is space left before Bruce, does anyone know why this is happening?

The result is in the picture:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try `\noindent{\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}{Bruce Dickinson}}\\ `.

Comment: hey marmot, I did try that and it worked! I would like to understand why am I forced to use noindent though. If I write normal text it doesn't indent it as you can see from address... could you explain me why?

Comment: You use a document class that comes with indents at the beginning of a paragraph. `\\ ` does *not* end a paragraph, and you should not use it this way. From what I see, you are not using the document class that might be optimal for your task. It looks to me that you are writing a letter, and there are several document classes for that, perhaps [scrletter](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrletter?lang=en) may be more appropriate.

Comment: @marmot I am writing a CV, thanks for the explanation

Comment: There are also dedicated CV document classes. (Sorry for misinterpreting your document!)

Comment: I am actually working over a template cv I found over the internet, which classes would you suggest?